# Execution flow diagram (call-stack) of recursive count-down

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-visualization

I have this code:

```
public class RecurLoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     printit(2);    

    }

    private static int printit(int n){

        if(n>0){
            printit(--n);
        }

      System.out.print(n+",");

      return n;
   }
}
```

I have drawn a execution flow/memory flow diagram for above program.  Is this diagram correct or do I need some changes to make it correct?

What I have drawn looks like this:

[image]

[Link to edit diagram](https://creately.com/diagram/hu6inaj32/EbReNdNSdRqJI9xMbmr0byn2iM8=)

[Link to view diagram](https://creately.com/diagram/hu6inaj32)

Comment: Wow, this diagram visually clearly communicates your _recursive_ algorithm: illustrated call-stack plus count-down iterator-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to add the method arguments in the diagram, for example:

```
printit(0) -- n=0, prints "0,", returns 0
printit(1) -- n=1, prints "0,", returns 0
printit(2) -- n=2, prints "1,", returns 1
main()
```

I don't think you need 4 drawings side by side for this, just one like this would be clear enough already.